# Nimbus L&F no border on JButtons?

Tags: swing, border, jbutton, opacity, nimbus

As the title says, I'm interested in removing the JButton's border when using Nimbus.
Something like:

```
myButton.setBorderPainted(false);
```

doesn't work, unfortunately.
I've looked into UIManager defaults and couldn't find any border color/opacity option. 
I'd really appreciate some help, if possible.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: After a very long time I found out the answer, if anyone will ever need it.   button.setContentAreaFilled(false);